# Matlab: How to read a file relative to the function location?

Tags: matlab, file, fopen

In Matlab: How can I read a data file that is located relative to the function that wants to read it, while the caller of the function is located somewhere else? So I have the following constellation:

```
X:\callScript.m
Y:\myFunction.m
Y:\data\dataFile.txt
```

*callScript.m*

```
addpath('Y:\');
myFunction();
```

*myFunction.m*

```
function myFunction()
    fid = fopen('./data/dataFile.txt'); % < does not work!
    % ... read something ...
    fclose(fid);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better way to do this, but this also do the trick

```
function myFunc()
    path_myFunc = which('myFunc'); % get myFunc's full path
    path_myFunc = path_myFunc(1:find(path_myFunc,10,'last'); % Find last '\'(=10)
    fid = fopen([path_myFunc,'\data\datafile.txt']);
    % ... read something ...
    fclose(fid);
end
```

Comment: I would recommend to use `path_myFunc = fileparts(which('myFunction'))` ([fileparts](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html)) to get the path of the function. After that use `fullfile(path_myFunc, 'data', 'datafile.txt')` ([fullfile](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html)) instead of `strcat` to build the full path.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a nice idea. Unfortunately, `which` returns an empty path for `myFunct`(`'myFunc' no found`)

Comment: this because you named your function "myFunction", so use `which('myFunction')`

Comment: no it is not ;-) I have just adapted my comment to your code

Comment: please double check the spelling of file and function name of `myFunc`, as well as all the calls (including `which`)

Comment: I found the (stupid) reason, the function was part of a package which I also had to add to the which statement.